# Font size setting is missed in iPhone application

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Can you add a setting for choosing font size in iPhone mobile app?

It's hard to read questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already change the text size through the OS by going to:

> Settings → Display & Brightness → Text Size

For comparison here is this question at its smallest text size:

> [image]

And largest:

> [image]

Note, since iOS 11 you can add a text size control to the control centre (go to *Settings → Control Centre → Customize Controls*) so you can change the text size on the fly by swiping up the control centre.

Comment: I know that, but It's still noticeably smaller than the text in Mail. The menu's font is fine, didn't even need to be so big, but the body text is still smallish.

Answer (score 1):

1st: you should start by going to to Settings

then go to General

then go to Accessibility

then Larger Text

Turn on Larger Accessibility Sizes

Drag the slider to select the font size you want